# Best way to fetch the value from the list of Maps in groovy

Tags: groovy

```
def jobsInView = [
   ["name":"hello", "age":"45","language":"english"],
   ["name":"hi", "age":"22","language":"english"],
   ["name":"ravi", "age":"22","language":"spanish"] 
]
```

I need to fetch the values of the key "name" in to the list, like below:

```
def listOfNames = ["hello","hi","ravi"]
```

Please let me know the best way to fetch the values like above.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator):

```
def names = jobsInView*.name
```

Comment: Or just `jobsInView.name`

Comment: @Raju if you found the answer useful, please accept it.